# Размер изображения Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли в подсказки при редактировании css кода, в контексте класса или id, при добавлении background или background-image, и написании width: дальше появлялась подсказка с размером картинки. Подобное реализовано в intellij idea[image: введите сюда описание изображения]